# Using main classpath resource instead of test one at will

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have some code which expects a particular resource in the bundle as an input for certain operation. This resource is stored in `src/main/resources`.
For testing, I have a lighter-test version of the file in `src/test/resources`. That way I trick the code for using that version when testing.

The problem is I included an integration test as well, which I'd like to use the production resource instead of the test one, but as the test is executed on test phase, it reads the test version.

How can I discriminate so my integration test forgets about `/src/test/resources/foobar.txt` and uses `/src/test/main/foobar.txt` ?

P.S: I know I could use mockito's Whitebox.setInternalState(), but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant and decoupled way

Comment: By the sounds of it, i'm guessing you have "foobar.txt" hardcoded somewhere. Can you not give them different names and add the path as a parameter to the classes that need them so you can explicitly specify which file to use?

Comment: The thing is that this file is a resource file within the jar, and does not make a lot of sense to me expose that property to the operators of the app. There are a lot of properties already, and let alone if they are internal implementation details

Comment: I wasn't referring to a property. I meant if you have it hardcoded in class A then you could perhaps pass the path in as a parameter. The calling classes could then pass in test_foobar.txt or prod_foobar.txt.